# Trying to put 2 locations of real people on map

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to have 2 locations on Map, but it only shows me my own. I want that 2 different people will be able to see each other on their map. I'm using firebase, and It looks like this:

[image]

This is my onMapReady:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
```

and this is my onLocationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;
    if (currentLocationMarker != null)
    {
        currentLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("current location");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

    locations.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .setValue(new Tracking(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                    String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude()),
                    String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLongitude())));


    currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    if (client != null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
    }

}
```

please help.
I already tried to put mapFragments and it didn't work and also tried to put this code in my onMapReady and the app stopped:

```
refDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(
                   dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Long.class),
                   dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Long.class)
           );
           mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                   .position(newLocation)
                   .title(dataSnapshot.getKey()));

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

Comment: Usually helpful to explain what doesn't work.  Reader is left to assume 'refDatabase' is a reference to the 'Locations' node.  So why are you getting lat/lng as Long rather than Float or Double?  also the child nodes are 'lat' and 'lng' not 'latitude', 'longitude'.

Comment: how to make  'refDatabase' reference to the 'Locations' node? I don't know.